# Premiere Pro CC 2017 - Displacement map

Tags: premiere, effects, distortion

Can't find it:
[image]

Is it a plugin I have to import?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displacement map effect relies on another layer as a source for the map. Since Premiere doesn't have unique layers like AE does it doesn't support this plugin. If you have After Effects then replace the shot with an after effects comp (right-click then choose Replace With After Effects Composition) and apply the effect in AE.